# Mapping predecessors and successors, and visualizing it all

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, enterprise-geodatabase, popup, database

I have a current project that involves relocation of hundreds of utilities. Before a utility can be relocated, there are several utilities lines that that have to relocated prior (predecessors).

We have those utilities mapped out as polylines and shown within a simple ArcGIS Web app. Here is an example of how our attribute table looks:

[image: Utilities]

Our goal in the web app is to be able to click on any utility, click on a button to show predecessors and one for successors, and see it all on a map.

I'm thinking of creating two 1:M relationships for both the successors and predecessors as a start, but it looking to see if anyone else has had this type of project.

Comment: You seem to be seeking a discussion and have not asked a focused question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can figure a way to make ArcGIS do a select of other layers when you click a layer (perhaps using layer actions to create a 'button', and then do a selection based on spatial intersection. I'd set up the attribute table as one field per predecessor so when you select a record, you can 'query' from a list of other utilities to determine if those other line layers are predecessors/successors, and only then run the spatial select to determine if they intersect, and you need to worry about them.